# Перевести содержимое файла в словарь другого вида

Tags: python, файлы, словари, dict

Есть файл, содержимое которого выводится в виде {"user_id": "1840e0b9d4", "category": "Продукты"}. Нужно перевести содержимое файла в вид : {‘1840e0b9d4’: ‘Продукты’, …}

Ниже мой код. Выводит корректно, но правда только одно значение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, по алгоритму.
Как добавить ключ:значение в новый словарь в нужном виде?

```
i = 0
dic = {}

with open('purchase_log.txt','r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() #
        
        dict_ = json.loads(line) 
        
        for x in dict_.items():
            key = dict_['user_id']
            value = dict_['category']
            dic = {key : value}
                  
        i = i+1
        if i > 10:
            break
        
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in dict_.items():
    key = dict_['user_id']
    value = dict_['category']
    dic = {key : value}
```

Зачем вам тут цикл? Вы `x` всё-равно не используете. Вот так словарь будет пополняться, а не создаваться заново:

```
key = dict_['user_id']
value = dict_['category']
dic[key] = value
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Зачем х - я просто подумала, что итерация нужна не только внутри словаря. Сейчас вывод такой: {'user_id': 'category', '1840e0b9d4': 'Продукты', '4e4f90fcfb': 'Электроника', 'afea8d72fc': 'Электроника', '373a6055fe': 'Бытовая техника', '9b2ab046f3': 'Электроника', '9f39d307c3': 'Электроника', '44edeffc91': 'Продукты', '704474fa2d': 'Продукты', '1de31be403': 'Бытовая техника', 'b71f36a5e4': 'Продукты'}

Comment: Не подскажете, как мне вывести списком, а не строкой?

Comment: Вопрос выше снимается - разобралась

Comment: @ЕкатеринаСавченкова, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)